# Pass Response (File) From Django to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, django, httpresponse, filereader

I am trying to achieve the following:

1. Create a file in Django/Python (for instance a Word Document with the python-docx module)
2. Pass the response (the complete file) to JavaScript, so I can do other stuff with this (for instance with the Office Javascript API)

I am not sure, whether this is possible (I have only seen ways to pass simple JSON files), but I would love some help. I am now able to create the file and download this to the client's desktop. Then the client has to go through its desktop in order to search for the file and upload it, so JavaScript can work with it (through FileReader). Ideally, I would like to directly send the file to Javascript without all the unnecessary steps. My code:

In template.html:

```
# To download the created file from Django/Python
<input type="button" value="Download"
   onclick="window.open('filemaker/download_my_file', '_self')">

# To select the file, so Javascript can use it 
<input type='file' id='test'>
```

In template.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // The document is ready
    $('#test').change(insertFile);
});

function insertFile(){
    var myFile = document.getElementById("test");
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (event) {
        // some JavaScript Stuff
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(myFile.files[0]);
}
```

In urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('/download_my_file', views.create_file_function),
]
```

In views.py:

```
def create_file_function():
    document = Document()
    document.add_heading('Document Title', 0)

    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=aass.docx'
    document.save(response)

    return response
```

Any ideas how to get the response from create_file_function() to var MyFile in insertFile() would be really appreciated. Many thanks for your help!